# Redis Sentinel load balancing

Tags: redis, load-balancing, jedis, sentinel

I have redis sentinel setup with 1 master and 2 slaves (this has to be done for production environment), can anyone please suggest how to achieve load balancing effectively in this case !!
I'm new to redis as well as to load balancing.

TIA

Comment: What do you want to load balance?

Comment: This is acheived in the redis.conf as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52935434/how-can-i-load-balance-reads-on-a-master-slave-redis-setup)

Comment: @VeKe, a sentinel with a master and 2 slaves setup we have and we want to load balance the requests from clients to these sentinel instances, read is our priority

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: @VeKe, no we are not using spring

Comment: @veke, can you please suggest any approach or any document kind of thing, i dont anything at all about load balancing so!

Comment: I will share with you in few hours, its laye night on country where I am :)